# multiprocessing.Process does not handle `sys.exit` arguments the same as Python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to coerce `multiprocessing.Process` into giving me the same exit code as the Python interpreter, but it behaves differently depending on how I invoke `sys.exit`. For example:

```python
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys


def run(fn):
    p = Process(target=fn)
    p.start()
    p.join()
    return p.exitcode


print(run(lambda: sys.exit(2)))
print(run(lambda: sys.exit(None)))
print(run(lambda: sys.exit()))
```

when executed yields:

```sh
$ python exit.py
2
1
1
```

but when I execute Python directly I see different results:

```sh
$ for arg in 2 None ''; do python -c "import sys; sys.exit($arg)"; echo $?; done
2
0
0
```

So multiprocessing clearly respects `sys.exit` (since `sys.exit(2)` works), but behaves differently with `sys.exit()` and `sys.exit(None)`.

I can work around this easily enough by wrapping the target function, like

```python
try:
    target()
except SystemExit as e:
    if not e.args:
        e.args = (0,)
        e.code = 0
    raise
```

but what is the reason (and justification, if applicable) for this difference in behavior?

Technically, I see [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blame/1cffd0eed313011c0c2bb071c8affeb4a7ed05c7/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#L307) that the line causing this behavior is from the original introduction of multiprocessing into the standard library. I think the behavior is incorrect but want to understand why it is that way before creating an issue.

Comment: That looks like a bug to me, especially since `sys.exit(0)` seems to give an exit code of 0.

Comment: There have been [three](https://bugs.python.org/issue13854) [other](https://bugs.python.org/issue19338) [bugs](https://bugs.python.org/issue23658) in `multiprocessing` related to bad `SystemExit` handling in the past that I can see.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks, I'll file the bug and add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in question is from the original [processing](https://pypi.org/project/processing/) module which was integrated into Python 2.6/3.0 as part of [PEP 371](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0371/). The original repository seems lost to time, so the "why" part of the question may not be answerable.

Given similar issues against `multiprocessing` when it differs from the Python behavior (e.g. [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue19338)), it would likely be considered a bug, so I have filed it as [bpo-35727](https://bugs.python.org/issue35727).